# Implementing Observables into a persistent queue library

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, observable

Currently writing a little persistent queue library that will read/write lines to a text file. Here is the add method, for example:

```
Queue.prototype.add = function(line, cb){

    getLock(this, err => {
        if(err){
            this.emit('error', err);
            releaseLock(err, cb);
        }
        else{
            fs.appendFile(this.filepath, line, err => {
               err && this.emit('error', err);
               releaseLock(err, cb);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

what I find quite awkward, is supporting event emitters and callbacks (or event emitters and promises).

In other words, for each method (add, peek, remove) on the queue, I need to return/callback a result that's specific to each call. Using an event emitter only means that the caller might act on a result that was not specific to the call they just made. So callbacks or promises here seem imperative - you can't use event emitters only.

What I am wondering is - can observables somehow solve the problem of having to pair callbacks with event emitters or promises with event emitters?

I am looking to find a way to implement this evented/asynchronous queue with only one type asynchronous callback mechanism. Maybe observables aren't the answer here, but I am looking for a good design pattern nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why do you need event emitters here.... If you use observables each subscriber will get the results/errors from their own call.

I would rewrite your method as such:

```
function appendFileObs(filePath, line){
    return Rx.Observable.create((obs) => {
        fs.appendFile(filePath, line, (err, result) => {
            if(err) obs.onError(err);
            else {
                obs.onNext(result);
                obs.onCompleted();
            }
        });
    });
});
// Similar for getLock and releaseLock


Queue.prototype.add = function(line){
    return getLockObs(this)
        .flatMap(() => appendFileObs(this.filePath, line))
        .flatMap(result => releaseLockObs(undefined).map(() => result))
        .catch((err) => {
            return releaseLockObs(err);
        });
};
```

On this solution I'm not proud that the stream has side effects inside, it's probably improvable but you get the idea.

This way, when someone calls .add(line).subscribe() it will get the result and the errors that happened on his call.

If you need to broadcast the errors that happen, you can use a BehaviourSubject, that's an observer and observable at the same time (useful stuff!)

Comment: Thanks this will help me out - is there also a way for a listener to listen to all events (using observables) that the queue emits? At the very least this is useful for debugging.

Comment: Oh I think you answered my question already by alluding to "BehaviorSubject"

Comment: I guess with observables it's not possible to chain methods, for example: queue.add(line1).add(line2).add(line3).subscribe() or is it?

Comment: I need to have an event emitter because there may be a subscriber to the queue that is listening for new items added to the queue. But that same subscriber will need to listen for errors, so if there is an error we have to emit it.

Comment: To the first question, about chaining them, no... it's not possible to do it that way... Each add method returns you an observable (think of it as a stream)... You can compose all observables with `flatMap` or Observable.forkJoin

Comment: On the second point, I think you still could use Observables but there's a limitation: Once you call `onError` on one stream, that stream is closed, finalized, so you can't send any more events. One way people use to fix this is by sending errors on `onNext` (an object like `{isSucessful:boolean, result:object}`), and using `onError` only on non-recoverable errors (crashes for instance). You can use an event emitter if you feel that's better for your case.

Comment: I meant I need to pair an event emitter with callbacks to get the behavior originally. With observables I was hoping to do away with the event emitter. That was one of the big reasons to use observables; so that I don't have to implement both callbacks and event emitters,

Comment: I think I don't understand the use case...  The solution I provided was for 2 kind of subscribers: Those who just want to know about the result of their `add` call, and another for those who want to get all calls, i.e. for logging, controlling number of errors, etc. From your last comment, though... I understand that one subscriber that calls `add` wants to know about the errors that may happen from another `add` call?

Comment: Well, an add error should never happen and if it does something is fairly wrong. But no, I don't think it's necessary for the subscriber that is readingAll() new messages on the queue to see the error from an add() method call.